# custom role and permissions for every user

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-security

let's say we have a user A  and a user B

User A  has role ROLE_USER AND PERMISSIONS TO READ WRITE AND UPDATE

User B has role ROLE_USER also BUT ONLY READ PERMISSSIONS

it's possible to do it ? and how?

and how can i get  the permissions table and role  in spring security object "grantAuthority"

i'm using spring boot and my class extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve custom roles you could implement your own "UserDetailsService". 
[Spring Security UserDetailsService](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-authentication-userdetailsservice)

Here you have an example:

```
@Service
public class UsuarioDetailsServiceImp implements UserDetailsService {

  @Autowired
  private UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository;

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
      if(email==null||email.isEmpty()){
          throw new UsernameNotFoundException("");
      }

      Usuario usuario = usuarioRepository.findByEmail(email);
      if(usuario==null){
          throw new UsernameNotFoundException("");
      }
      List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
      authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
      if(usuario.isAdmin()){
          authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
      }
      return new User(email,usuario.getPassword(),authorities);
  }
}
```

[Custom role based auth example](https://github.com/wwrrss/BootVtech)